# The required antiforgery cookie is not present error: When registering first user in new asp.net 5 project in Chrome only

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise and my dnx version is the latest (rc1-update 1). When I create a new web project from scratch with Individual User Accounts and I load the website and fill out the form to register the first user I instantly get the following error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

InvalidOperationException: The required antiforgery cookie "9tyjs755shX" is not present.
Microsoft.AspNet.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenStore.<GetRequestTokensAsync>d__4.MoveNext()

InvalidOperationException: The required antiforgery cookie "9tyjs755shX" is not present.
```

This has to be some kind of ASP.NET 5 bug because everything I am using is default and freshly installed. The error only happens when using Chrome browser. If anyone wants to reproduce simply create a new web app from scratch with individual user accounts, load the website in Chrome, try and register a user.

Comment: When you look at the POST in your browser dev tools network panel, does it have an antiforgery token field in the posted body **and** an antiforgery token cookie as well?

Comment: Very strange. This issue is only happening in Chrome. I am assuming no, it does not have an antiforgery token which is why it is erroring.

Comment: "Have you tried turning it off and on again."

i.e. remove browser history, it now works for me. How I found it: I tried it in Incognito mode and worked straight away without any code change.

Comment: I found related issue: [issues # 1234](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1234)

Answer (score 6):

One in the category of: *"Have you tried turning it off and on again."*

I've removed my browser history (cookies) and it now works.

How I found it: I tried it in Incognito mode and worked straight away without any code change.

Comment: I had the same error and using Incognito-Mode worked just fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just tried to reproduce your problem and cannot.

There are a couple of things to check;

1. View the source of the login page and ensure the
   __RequestVerificationToken hidden field is present
2. In Developer Tools look at  Cookies under The resources tab. Look
   for a cookie which has a matching value for the
   __RequestVerificationToken field.

Both must be present.

Comment: A small remark on #1: using the "old school" View Source option causes a new request to the page (in Chrome at least). Which probably changes the value that is supposed to match the "__RequestVerificationToken" hidden field(?) So I assume it's better to use "Inpect Elements" (F12/Developer tools) to view the HTML source.